# How to Implement angular push state on apache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I followed the directions for implementing push state by [codelord.net"](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/12/angularjs-how-to-setup-pushstate-with-html5mode/) and got the .htaccess code from [here](https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/).

When I click on a navigation link, the URL looks correct (http://writers-tryst-test.ron-tornambe.com/about) but a blank page is displayed for the home page and 404 NOT FOUND for all others.

I am a Linux newbie and a bit confused about where the .htaccess root file is located. I am on a GoDaddy shared server. I appended the code in the .htaccess file that is in the same folder that contains public_html.

**.htaccess** EDIT - new file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**angular JS**

```
angular.module('wtApp').config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
var wtApp = angular.module('wtApp', ['ngRoute'])

wtApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    // route for the writers page
    .when('/writers', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/writers.html',
        controller: 'writersController'
    })
```

...
**HTML**

```
    <base href="/" />
```

I have also tried prefixing the href's with a forward slash (/).

```
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Writers-Tryst">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a id="homepage" href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="writers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"> Writers</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="enablers" id="enablers-link" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> Enablers</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="about" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> About</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="privacy" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> Privacy/Rules</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="contact" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> Contact</a></li> 
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrites are a mess. Getting weird stuff like this: http://writers-tryst-test.ron-tornambe.com/writers-tryst-test.ron-tornambe.com/#//

Now, I worked on my own version of this, and I ended up using a Directory in the Apache config:

```
<Directory "S:/localhost/Apache24/Angular/routing-simple-evo">
  RewriteEngine on

  # Don't rewrite files or directories
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</Directory>
```

I think you could paste what's inside the directory tags right into your htaccess if you wanted, but for some reason the config file seemed to work best, or just happened to be what was working when I finally sorted this stuff out.

The only other things I'd point out are the order and group;ing of your routing commands look different than all the tutorials I looked at today. The following is what worked for me:

```
// create the module and name it RoutingEvo
// also include ngRoute for all our routing needs
var RoutingEvo = angular.module('RoutingEvo', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
RoutingEvo.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'http://angular.dev/routing-simple-evo/views/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'http://angular.dev/routing-simple-evo/views/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'http://angular.dev/routing-simple-evo/views/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});
```

//log some info from the routing:

```
RoutingEvo.run([
  '$rootScope',
  function($rootScope) {
    // see what's going on when the route tries to change
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
      // both newUrl and oldUrl are strings
      console.log('Starting to leave %s to go to %s', oldUrl, newUrl);
    });
  }
]);

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
RoutingEvo.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

RoutingEvo.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

RoutingEvo.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

I put this together mostly from the following:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

-----OLD--------

Add the following to the .htaccess file in your app's root folder (create an .htaccess file if one doesn't exist.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rob but I am still getting HTTP 404 (GET /accounts) when reloading a page.

Comment: I added the htaccess file that includes your answer. Could the first <IfModule be interfering somehow?

Comment: Only if the module isn't present/enabled. I presume your actual code has the About route configured? ...

Comment: Yes, the about route is defined. The 404 is issued for all links except home.

Comment: Thanks for your Herculean effort. I tried copying the contents of the Directory but it didn;t work. I am on a Godaddy shared server.  I do not see an Apache config file anywhere. Is this something I can create?